# Check if signal drifts are temperature related

Tags: signal, temperature, optoelectronics, drift

Let’s say I have an output signal vs time plot data of some opto-electrical device (a black box for me). If the device is exposed to sunlight the signal starts to drift to higher values.

Is there a way, using data anaylsis, to "proove" that the drifts are solely heating/temperature problem, like curve fitting analysis ?

Comment: Do you know when the exposure happened? Can you simulate or estimate the temperature? (I.e., have you any information except that plot?)

Comment: Do you have a spare refrigerator? I'm not sure what kind of proof you want, but if I put a device in a temperature chamber and observe a signal drift directly correlated to temperature, I'd call that proof.

Comment: In optoelectronics, if the signal drifts and you aren't already taking strong measures to control temperature, then temperature is almost always the dominant cause of drift. Is this an O/E or E/O device?

Comment: If you can modulate and measure the temperature and the output signal change follows the same profile as the temperature curve it's pretty self evident.

Comment: Thermal tests are easy to verify with a light source. But a typical PD may experience up to 5% rise with 50'C rise at 1000 lux.  Not sure about 100k lux of full sun,  but your lack of data is overwhelming. Hmm is this an oxymoron?

Comment: It is an infra-red proximity sensor with a photodiode and an LED, 
where the output signal should be immune to ambient light.

For example
https://www.vishay.com/docs/84150/vcnl3020.pdf.

But suppose I don't have the device to make test, and only have the signal data. 
The temperature difference could be max about 30 Degrees and I know at what time 
the exposure happened and that it is 1 min long.
But the data logging is stopped during the exposure.